# How to insert a text in EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

How to insert a text in `EditText` at the cursor position? `editText.setText` erases the current text and sets the new one, which is not what I want. `editText.setText(editText.getText() + "my text");` inserts the text at the end, that's also not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very easy to do this :

```
int start =editText.getSelectionStart(); //Get cursor position with this function
String str = "my text";//String you want to insert
editText.getText().insert(start, str); //This will get the text and insert the String str at the current position.
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

are you perhaps talking about settings the hint text ?

```
editText.setHint("Enter Text Here");
```

in XML

```
android:hint="Enter Text Here"
```

If this is not what you are looking for then please alaborate the problem a bit more

Answer (score 0):

Add *\n* before the text you want to add...

var.setText(var.getText() + "\nnewtext");